# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified with gcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Am facing ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified error
I just make new app

```
rails new app_name
```

Controller Code:

```
class HelloWorldController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: 'Hello, world!'
  end
end
```

Gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'gcloud'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

database.yml

```
development:
```

dataset_id: iddddd

production:
  dataset_id: iddddd

[image]